# Android, services passing a UI object

Tags: java, android

I'm slightly struggling with this.As a simple exercise I want to pass a UI object such as a Label from the Activity to the Service to later change it's text and I'm really struggling. I've noticed a few ways of implementing:

1. Use a broadcast messenger as well.
2. Package the object in a Packable wrapper.

I'm a bit confused with which to go for and some of the examples I followed are a bit unclear. With option number 1, I'm imagining the message that the broadcast messenger should be received by the activity to indicate that the service has ended. Is that right?

And option number two, I feel a bit confused regarding what areas I need to actually implement to get it working.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want in short is IPC (Inter-Process Communication). In Android, to communicate 2 different processes -an application and a service in your case- you need to either define and implement an [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html); or pass the objects through [`Message`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html), which requires the classes to pass to implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

I suggest you use AIDL, it's much easier and avoids the many headaches using `Parcelable`.